# Auto-fill an id from another controller in a CakePHP form

Tags: mysql, forms, cakephp, view, controllers

Hey trying to get an id from one Controller (Template) to another (Field). Trying to get Template's id to automatically appear in the add (view) input field in the form.

FieldsController with the segment which we have tried:

```
$template = $this->Template->find('first');
$current_template = $this->Template->request->data($template['Template']['id']);
```

Input field from the add Fields view:

```
 echo $this->Form->input('templates_id', array('label'=>'Template ID: ', 'type' => 'text', 'default' => $current_template['templates_id']));
```

So what can we do to get this task done? I thought what I tried would have worked, but doesn't, comes up with "Call to a member function find() on a non-object."

'templates_id' is the foreign key in the 'Field' table which links to 'id' in the 'Template' table.

EDIT:

Added LoadModel (below) and spits out an error: Call to a member function data() on a non-object.

Are we doing the below correctly? Or should it be $this->request->data($template['Template']['id']);

```
$this->loadModel('Template');
    $template = $this->Template->find('first');
    $current_template = $this->Template->request->data($template['Template']['id']);
```

EDIT 2:

FieldsController with add function:

```
function add(){

    $this->set('title_for_layout', 'Please Enter Your Invoice Headings');
    $this->set('stylesheet_used', 'style');
    $this->set('image_used', 'eBOXLogo.jpg');   

    $this->Session->setFlash("Please create your required fields.");


    $this->loadModel('Template');
    $template = $this->Template->find('first');
    //$current_template = $template['Template']['id'];

    // right way to do it, but Template is undefined, and says undefined var
    //$current_template = $this->request->data['Template']['id'];

    // makes sense with the find, no errors, but still doesnt print in form, says undefined var
    $current_template = $this->request->data($template['Template']['id']);

        if($this->request->is('post'))
        {

        $this->Field->create(); 

        if ($this->Field->save($this->request->data)) 
        {   
            if($this->request->data['submit'] == "type_1") 
                { 
                    $this->Session->setFlash('The field has been saved');  
                    $this->redirect( array('controller' => 'fields','action' => 'add'));
                } 
                if($this->request->data['submit'] == "type_2") 
                { 
                    $this->Session->setFlash('The template has been saved'); 
                    $this->redirect( array('controller' => 'templates','action' => 'index'));
                } 


        }
        else
        {
            $this->Session->setFlash('The field could not be saved. Please, try again.'); 
        } 
    } 
  }
```

Form from the view called add:

```
<?php


    echo $this->Form->create('Field', array('action'=>'add'));


    echo $this->Form->create('Field', array('action'=>'add'));
    echo $this->Form->input('name', array('label'=>'Name: '));
    echo $this->Form->input('description', array('label'=>'Description: '));
    echo $this->Form->input('templates_id', array('label'=>'Template ID: ', 'type' => 'text', 'default' => $current_template['templates_id']));//this would be the conventional fk fieldname
    echo $this->Form->button('Continue adding fields', array('name' => 'submit', 'value' => 'type_1'));
    echo $this->Form->button('Finish adding fields', array('name' => 'submit', 'value' => 'type_2'));
    echo $this->Form->end();


?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$this->Template->request->data($template['Template']['id']);
```

is wrong.

Look at the MVC pattern:
[image]

The dispatcher sends data to a controller.

Now look at your code:

```
 $this->Template->request->data($template['Template']['id']);


$this
```

is a controller.

```
->Template
```

calls the associated model.

```
request->data()
```

calls a function from this Model with data from the View.

In short: you're passing data form the View to the Model, which breaks the MVC pattern.

It should be:

```
 $this->request->data['Template']['id'];
```

EDIT:
Two problems I think:

1. I think it should be:

   $current_template = $this->request->data['Field']['template_id'];
2. `$current_template = $this->request->data($template['Template']['id']);`

This variable is not set.

Put something like this:

```
$this->set(compact('current_template'));
```

Comment: $this->loadModel('Template');
$current_template = $this->request->data['Template']['id'];

Thanks, have got the above. But now says: 'Undefined index Template' and on the form says 'undefined variable current_template', when I have defined it in the controller, as you can see above.

So how would I fix these?

Comment: Seems you're making several mistakes. Could you put the code of the form in the view and the code of the method in the controller?

Comment: Code added, as you can see, have tried a couple different things.

Comment: $current_template = $this->request->data['Field']['template_id'];
That throws an error: Undefined index: Field.

Put this: $this->set(compact('current_template')); in the controller and still says undefined variable current_template.

Comment: OK. Then use firebug to look what data are sent from the view. That should help you solve the first problem.

Comment: use debug() on current_template. It probably fails because it is not defined in the controller: it depends on $this->request, which may contain no data if the method is not called from a form.

Answer (score 0):

To get the data from another model you have to load it first:

```
$this->loadModel('Template');
$this->Template->find('first');
```

Comment: just updated code above, and says 'Call to a member function data() on a non-object.' Are we using $this->data correct?

Comment: I think this is wrong '$this->Template->request->data($template['Template']['id'])'
you can check your data using pr($template);die; and then assign as per structure
This should be like :
    $current_template = $template['Template']['id'];

Comment: No that doesn't work either.

Played around with debug, looks like find('first') only grabs the first one (DUH!) so isn't actually grabbing the right one nor are we able to post it to the input box. Any other ideas?